# How to give unique ids to each child div created dynamically?

Tags: javascript

The function displays eight elements on click in dynamically created divs using the `slice()` method. How can I give a unique **id** to each `div`? Your suggestions would be of great help to me.

```
var words = [40];
var count = 0;
var x = "";

function nextElems() {
    var newArray = words.slice(count, count + 8);

    for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        x += '<div class=box>' + newArray[i] + '</div>';
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x;
    }

    x = "";
    count += 8;
}
```

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('container');
var first = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

first.id = 'one';
```

Comment: It's unclear what `document.getElementById('container')` returns. Also, you should do `document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x;` only *after* the for-loop is done. `innerHTML` is a very expensive method because it causes a reflow in the browser.

Comment: Why not using a counter `X` and use it to generate IDs formatted as `uniqueid_X`?

Comment: @TarunRathore I agree with GalAbra's comment for creating the unique ids, but you have an issue in your loop: `x += '<div class=box>' + newArray[i] + '</div>';` Should have quotes around the value of class like so: `x += '<div class="box">' + newArray[i] + '</div>';`

Comment: @RyanWilson That is not necessary. Attribute values can be unquoted as long as they do not contain a space character. That is explicitly allowed by the specification.

Comment: @connexo Interesting, I always thought you needed the quotations, can you post a link or the spec text here for that?

Comment: @RyanWilson https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#unquoted, or for the editor's draft for 5.3, here: https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#unquoted

Comment: @connexo Thanks a lot, this will save me time when appending to the DOM. I appreciate it.

Comment: *The attribute name, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by the attribute value, which, in addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, must not contain any literal space characters, any U+0022 QUOTATION MARK characters ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters ('), U+003D EQUALS SIGN characters (=), U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN characters (<), U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN characters (>), or U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT characters (`), and must not be the empty string.*

Answer (score 2):

You can do it right inside the for loop while it's iterating:

```
for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)

{
    x += '<div id="box-' + i + '"> class="box">' + newArray[i] + '</div>';

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use assign an ID inside the text string.

Here are a couple of other things you can do to improve this code:

1. Move the getElementById outside the loop
2. use js methods instead of string concatenation

Something like this (untested):

```
// get the container
container = document.getElementById('container');

for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)
{
  // create a div
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  // add attributes
  div.setAttribute("id", "box-" + i);
  div.setAttribute("class", "box");

  // create text node
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("This is div #" + i);

  // add text to div
  div.appendChild(textnode); 

  // append to container
  container.appendChild(div); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about giving it the id when creating? Also put the `class=box` in quotations like so -> `class="box"`.

And add the whole div construct only once after the for loop. Because right now you are basically overwriting the whole thing multiple times.

```
var words = [40];

var count = 0;

var x = "";

function nextElems() {

    var newArray = words.slice(count, count + 8);

    for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)

    {
        // Change class and add custom id
        x += '<div class="box" id="box-'+i+'">' + newArray[i] + '</div>';
    }

    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x; // Add divs after for loop

    x = "";

    count += 8;
}
```

Now each box has a unique id going from box-0, box-1, ... to box-n